# uneven probability - how to detect rigging?

Tags: probability

Imagine a video game in which the players has some percentage chance to hit a shot. (XCOM, for example)

The percentage chance presented for each shot is dependent on various environmental factors such as distance between shooter and target, weather etc. Effectively, you get uneven probability to land each shot. (e.g.: 99%, 95%, 83%, 10% etc.)

Now, imagine that a player modified the game's code so that the actual probability to hit a shot is higher than the probability shown in the game. (e.g.: 90% to hit becomes 99%, 10% becomes 20% etc.)

How can someone detect rigging using only a list of the shown percentage and the binary results of the shots? The data may look like this:

| Shown percentage | Hit? |
| --- | --- |
| 90% | yes |
| 55% | yes |
| 30% | no |
| ... |  |

Comment: One way would be to use the Central Limit Theorem. A typical example would be to toss a coin say 10,000 and ask if head came 5,500 is this coin fair? From CLT you get that for large $n$ the difference between heads and tails should be of the order $\sqrt n$ that is about 100. In this case, coin is bias to flip to head with probability like 95%.

Comment: but the probability of tossing a fair coin that is the same each time. How do you check for rigging when you are rolling a dice that has a different number of faces each time?

Comment: you mean, each time you toss you have a different number of faces? I do not know if it can be modeled at all. Independence and identical distribution is the key for such things.

Comment: So you just didn't read the question at all